# D3 Choosing value from drop down menu for updating chart

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js, donut-chart

I'm trying to update my donut chart by using a drop down menu, however, I received two errors upon executing my function. What I am creating is that a single donut chart that represents a particular hospital and numerous categories such as sickness, injuries, etc. I have put my dataset into a nested data array using d3.nest().

Method:

```
 d3.json("hospitals.json", function (error, dataset) {

 if(error) throw error;

 var categoryByHospitals = d3.nest()
 .key(function(d) {return d.hospitalName;})
 .entries(dataset);

 categoryByHospitals.forEach(function(object) {
    object.values.forEach(function(d) {
        d.count = +d.count;
        d.enabled = true;
    });
```

I am using d3 v4 and following this website for my donut chart: https://bl.ocks.org/tezzutezzu/c2653d42ffb4ecc01ffe2d6c97b2ee5e

Below contains a screenshot and code

1. Screenshot

[image]

2. JavaScript code

   ```
    var timeDuration = 600;
    var firstTime = true;


    var width = 800;
    var height = 800;


    var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
    var donutWidth = 100; 


    var legendRectSize = 25;
    var legendSpacing = 6; 

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20b);

    var svg = d3.select('#chart') 
   .append('svg') 
   .attr('width', width) 
   .attr('height', height)
   .append('g') 
   .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) + ',' + (height / 2) + ')'); 

    var arc = d3.arc()
   .innerRadius(radius - donutWidth)
   .outerRadius(radius); 

    var pie = d3.pie() 
   .value(function(d) { return d.count; }) 
   .sort(null); 

    var total = d3.sum(dataset, d => d.count);


    var newTotal = d3.select('.new-total-holder')
   .append('span')
   .attr('class', 'newTotal').text(total);


    var tooltip = d3.select('#chart') 
   .append('div')                                     
   .attr('class', 'tooltip'); 

    tooltip.append('div') 
   .attr('class', 'label'); 
    tooltip.append('div') 
   .attr('class', 'count');                   
    tooltip.append('div')   
   .attr('class', 'percent'); 


    var path = svg.selectAll('path') 
   .data(pie(categoryByHospitals[17].values)) //.data(pie(dataset)) 
   .enter() 
   .append('path') 
   .attr('d', arc) 
   .attr('fill', function(d) { return color(d.data.category); }) 
   .each(function(d) { this._current - d; });


   path.on('mouseover', function(d) { 
   //doesn't work
   var total = d3.sum(d3.values(categoryByHospitals).map(function(d) { 
       return (d.enabled) ? d.count : 0;                 
   }));
   var percent = Math.round(1000 * d.data.count / total) / 10; 
   tooltip.select('.label').html(d.data.label);           
   tooltip.select('.count').html('Count: ' + d.data.count); 
   tooltip.select('.percent').html(percent + '%') 
   tooltip.style('display', 'block');                   
   });

   path.on('mouseout', function() {                        
   tooltip.style('display', 'none'); 
   });

   path.on('mousemove', function(d) {                 
   tooltip.style('top', (d3.event.layerY + 10) + 'px') 
       .style('left', (d3.event.layerX + 10) + 'px');
   });


    var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend') 
   .data(color.domain()) 
   .enter() 
   .append('g') 
   .attr('class', 'legend') 
   .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
       var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;      
       var offset = height * color.domain().length / 2; 
       var horz = -2 * legendRectSize; 
       var vert = i * height - offset;    
       return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + vert + ')'; 
    });


    legend.append('rect')                                  
   .attr('width', legendRectSize)
   .attr('height', legendRectSize) 
   .style('fill', color) 
   .style('stroke', color)
   .on('click', function(label) {
       var rect = d3.select(this); 
       var enabled = true; 
       var totalEnabled =   d3.sum(d3.values(categoryByHospitals).map(function(d) { 
           return (d.value.enabled) ? 1 : 0;
       }));
       if (rect.attr('class') === 'disabled') { 
           rect.attr('class', ''); 
       } else { // else
           if (totalEnabled < 2) return; 
           rect.attr('class', 'disabled'); 
           enabled = false; 
       }

       pie.value(function(d) {
           if (d.category === label) d.value.enabled = enabled; 
           return (d.value.enabled) ? d.value.count : 0;
       });

       path = path.data(pie(categoryByHospitals[17].values)); 

       path.transition() 
           .duration(750) 
           .attrTween('d', function(d) { 
               var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d); // this = current path element
               this._current = interpolate(0); 
               return function(t) {
                   return arc(interpolate(t));
               };
           });


       var newTotalCalc = d3.sum(categoryByHospitals.filter(function(d) { return d.enabled; }), d => d.count)
           // console.log(newTotalCalc);


       newTotal.text(newTotalCalc);
   });

   legend.append('text')
   .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
   .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
   .text(function(d) { return d; }); // return label



   //Filter by hospital
   var menu = d3.select(".dropDownMenu").selectAll("option")
   .data(categoryByHospitals)
   .enter()
   .append("option");

   menu.attr("value", function(d) { return d.key; })
   .on("change", change)
   .each(change)
   .property("checked", true);


   function change(category) {

   var path = svg.selectAll("path");
   var data0 = path.data(),
       data1 = pie(category.values);

   path = path.data(data1, key);

   path
       .transition()
       .duration(timeDuration)
       .attrTween("d", arcTween)

   path
       .enter()
       .append("path")
       .each(function(d, i) {

           var narc = findNeighborArc(i, data0, data1, key);

           if (narc) {
               this._current = narc;
               this._previous = narc;

           } else {
               this._current = d;
           }
       })

   .attr("fill", function(d, i) {

           return color(d.data.category)
       })
       .transition()
       .duration(timeDuration)
       .attrTween("d", arcTween)

   path
       .exit()
       .transition()
       .duration(timeDuration)
       .attrTween("d", function(d, index) {
           var currentIndex = this._previous.data.category;
           var i = d3.interpolateObject(d, this._previous);

           return function(t) {
               return arc(i(t))
           }

       })

      .remove()

      firstTime = false;

    }


    function key(d) {
     return d.data.category;
    }

    function type(d) {
      d.count = +d.count;
      return d;
    }

    function findNeighborArc(i, data0, data1, key) {
      var d;

       if (d = findPreceding(i, data0, data1, key)) {
       var obj = cloneObj(d)
       obj.startAngle = d.endAngle;
       return obj;
   } else if (d = findFollowing(i, data0, data1, key)) {
       var obj = cloneObj(d)
       obj.startAngle = d.endAngle;
       return obj;

   }

    return null
   }

    function findPreceding(i, data0, data1, key) {
       var m = data0.length;
       while (--i >= 0) {
       var k = key(data1[i]);

       for (var j = 0; j < m; j++) {
           if (key(data0[j]) === k) return data0[j];
       }
      }
     }

   function findFollowing(i, data0, data1, key) {
   var n = data1.length,
       m = data0.length;

   while (++i < n) {
       var k = key(data1[i]);

       for (var j = 0; j < m; j++) {
           if (key(data0[j]) === k) return data0[j];
       }
     }
   }

   function arcTween(d) {
   var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);

     this._current = i(0);

     return function(t) {
        return arc(i(t))
     }
   }

   function cloneObj(obj) {
   var o = {};

   for (var i in obj) {
       o[i] = obj[i];
   }

     return o;
   }
   ```
3. JSON file

   ```
    [{"hospitalName": "hospital1", "label":"100", "category": "Sickness", "females":"11", "males":"0", "unknown":"0", "count": "11"},
     {"hospitalName": "hospital1", "label": "321.0", "category": "Injury", "females":"0", "males":"1", "unknown":"2", "count": "3"},
     {"hospitalName": "hospital1" "label": "211","category": "Mental Disorders", "females":"2", "males":"0", "unknown":"3", "count": "5"},
     {"hospitalName": "hospital1","label": "254", "category": "Diseases","females":"1", "males":"0", "unknown":"0", "count": "1"},
     {"hospitalName": "hospital2","label": "000", "category": "None", "females":"2", "males":"0", "unknown":"0", "count": "2"},
     {"hospitalName": "hospital2", "label": "892.3", "category": "Symptoms","females":"9", "males":"2", "unknown":"0", "count": "11"}, 
     {"hospitalName": "hospital3","label": "000", "category": "None", "females":"1", "males":"0", "unknown":"0", "count": "1"},
     {"hospitalName": "hospital3", "label": "100", "category": "Sickness","females":"2", "males":"2", "unknown":"0", "count": "4"}]
   ```
4. HTML

   ```
     <!doctype html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>D3 Visualization-Donut Chart (V2)</title>
     <link href="style(v2).css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
     </head>

     <body>

     <div class="dropDownMenu">
       <select id="selection">
       <option id="mtf1" value="hospital1">hospital 1</option>
       <option id="mtf2" value="hospital2">hospital 2</option>
       <option id="mtf3" value="hospital3">hospital 3</option>
       </select>
    </div>


    <div id="chart"></div>

    </body>

    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.js'>.    </script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.min.js'></script>
    <script src="scriptsv2.js"></script>

    </html>
   ```

Comment: Can you post more of your code, HTML and the full JS file please?

Comment: Okay. I edited my post to add my HTML and other code.

Comment: Thanks, there's still things missing from your javascript file though. Such as 'diagnosisByMtfs', could you please update your JS code too?

Comment: Hi @REEE Actually that variable was a typing mistake that I named to hold the nested data array. And so, I changed it from "diagnosisByMtfs" to "categoryByHospitals".

Comment: I'm just working through your code now, what is clicking on the legend supposed to do? I know that's not what your question is about just so I'm not missing anything.

Comment: Hi @REEE Thank you for asking. The legend is suppose to be interactive meaning that if you deselect a label, the slice of the chart that coincides with the label disappears from view and vice versa. I have been trying to get that feature of the chart working as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176668/discussion-between-lsrain-and-reee).

Comment: I added some more comments on the chat, maybe,  you could take a view?

Comment: Hey @REEE I do not intend to be rude but have you had the chance to see the code that I posted days ago?

Comment: I just replied on the chat :). Sorry about the delay.